# How many documents per second can be created in a subcollection in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

From the documentation I know we can have 1 write per second in a document. Is there any limitation to how many documents can be created per seconds to a subcollection?

The reason I am asking this is, I am using the transaction to create a new document in subcollection of messages in my chat app, But as we know transactions do not have offline support, so should I use just set function to add a new message, will it be a correct choice?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information here to know exactly what limit applies to your use case.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions) says there are two possible limits you might encounter:

> Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain sequential values in an indexed field: 500 per second

So, if you are writing to a collection that has an index on a field that's being incremented sequentially as you write new documents, you will be limited to 500 per second.

Another limit you might reach instead:

> Maximum writes per second per database: 10,000 (up to 10 MiB per second)

If your new documents do not have a per-index limit on sequential fields, then you will be limited to 10,000 document writes be second total for **all** document writes in your Firestore instance.